# Urban Airship - Aggregating Similar Push Notifications on Messaging Platform

Tags: android, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

I am creating a messaging application, and like any mobile messaging service Push Notifications are needed for when the app isn't connected to the backend.

Let me use an example to out line the scenario I'm experiencing.

```
There is a conversation between User A & User B

// User B's application is idle (not receiving messages from our backend)

// User A sends User B a message
A --> B
```

Because User B isn't connected, he/she is sent a push notification beckoning him/her to open the app and sync the message.
User B's phone now has one notification on his/her lock screen, like so

```
Message from User A
```

then ...

```
// User A sends User B another message
A --> B
```

User B's phone now has two separate notifications on his/her lock screen from User A.
These messages read like this:

```
Message from User A
Message from User A
```

BUT, I would like the lockscreen to read something like this

```
Message from User A (2)
```

I am unsure how to get the notifications to aggregate once they reach the phone, assuming they have metadata attached to them that articulates who the "sender" of the message is.

Currently, this is the payload I am sending up to Urban Airship

```
function sendPushNotification (event, user) {
  if (event.type == 21 || event.type == 22 || event.type == 24) {
    var sender = event.sender.username;
    var alert = "from @" + sender;
    var reciever = user.username;
    var payload = {
      "audience": {
        "alias" : reciever
      },

      "device_types": [ "ios", "android" ],

      "notification": {

        "ios": {
          "alert": alert,
            "badge": "+1",
            "sound": "default",
            "extra": { "username": sender }
        },

        "android": {
          "alert": alert,
          "collapse_key": "inboxappco",
          "extra": { "username": sender }
        }

      }
    };
    console.log("Hello 2");
    pushNotification(payload);
  } else {
    // modularize for general purpose notifications
  }
}; // end sendPushNotification function
```

Any advice on how I can leverage the the sender metadata, to aggregate consecutive push notifications from the same person into one line item on the lock screen?

Thanks in advance SOF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your app will need to create your own custom push notification object and somehow get access to the NotificationManager

`PushManager.shared().setNotificationBuilder(new YourCustomNotificationObject());`

I'm not sure how Urban Airship exposes the NotificationManager, but you need to use the `setGroup("arbitrarygroupname")` accessor in your NotificationBuilder

Unless you are targeting minimum API level 20, then this is accessor is not available, so you have to use the v4+ NotificationCompat.Builder object, and make sure your support libraries are version 20 or higher.

**EDIT, as of UrbanAirship 4.0.3 for Android this is not possible**, server side you can keep track of a series of push notifications and use the `collapse_key` parameters with each push, `collapse_key` will replace push notifications of the same type, so your SERVER will have to send push notifications with different names, with the name being `Message from User A (2)` instead of letting the Android system handle that client side